# Setting java path in bashrc and cshrc

Tags: linux, bash, java, eclipse, path

My system java's version is 1.6, for running Eclipse I need jre 1.7. I've already downloaded and unpacked the archive of java 1.7, but I cant change the default path from `/usr/bin/java` to my unpacked folder path

mostly i'm using `cshrc` so I've made these change in the `.cshrc.user` file

```
set PATH = "$PATH":/path/to/java/jre1.7.0_67/bin
```

after sourcing `.cshrc.user` file, `java -version` still shows 1.6, which mean that nothing is changed, how do I change the default JAVA PATH?

Comment: I've not been using csh for a while but I remember using setenv instead of set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$PATH` is parsed from start to end until a match is found. So for example if your `$PATH` is:

```
/usr/bin:/path/to/jre6:/path/to/jre7
```

and you execute `java -jar something.jar`, shell will first look for executable `java` in `/usr/bin`. It won't find it there, so it will look in `/path/to/jre6`. It will find executable `java` in that directory so it will abandon further search and use that Java executable.

You have to add Java 7's path before path to Java 6 to use it.

Modifying `$PATH` is not the right way to switch between Java versions, though. You should rather use `update-alternatives`.

1. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to list available Java versions and switch between them. Your newly installed version won't be available yet.
2. Run `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/jre7/java 100` to register JRE7's java.
3. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` once again and choose JRE7's Java.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have java 1.6 earlier in your path.

```
env | grep PATH
```

should confirm this.

From [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

For C shell (csh), edit the startup file `~/.cshrc`:

```
set path=(/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin $path)
```

For bash, edit the startup file `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Note in both cases the new JDK is added **before** the existing path. When you edit the above files you should remove any references to JDK 1.6.